Catch error propagation
I'd like my function to work only for arrays with all positive members, eg:
myf[arr_] := Reverse@arr /; AllTrue[arr, Positive];

So
myf[{1,2}]
Output: {2,1}

and
myf[{-1,2}]
Output: myf[{-1,2}]

Well, but:
ToString /@ myf[{-1, 2}]
Output: Reverse::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Reverse[{-1, 2}].
Reverse[{-1, 2}]

I’m not very good at handling errors in Mathematica, so how to make the function not run,
before next calculations start?

so how to make the function not run, But this is what happened? The function was not called? The result of myf[{-1, 2}] is echoed back, since there was no function found that meets this signature.  What exactly do you want Mathematica to do in this case?

@Nasser, well may be to break all the next calculations and print message?

May be then you can use Abort? will this work for you?  myf[arr_] := If[ Not[AllTrue[arr, Positive]], Abort[], Reverse@arr] and now when you do ToString /@ myf[{-1, 2}] it will Abort.

myf[x_?VectorQ] /; AllTrue[x, Positive] := Reverse[x]

myf[x_?VectorQ] /; AnyTrue[x, Negative] := "Contains negative value(s)"

myf[x_] := "Not a real-valued vector"


myf[{1, 2, 3}]


{3, 2, 1}

myf[{1, -2, 3}]


"Contains negative value(s)"

myf[{1, {2}, 3}]


"Not a real-valued vector"

myf[{1, 2, 3 + 2 I}]


"Not a real-valued vector"

myf[{1, 2, "a"}]


"Not a real-valued vector"


One strategy could be as follows:
Clear[myf]
myf[arr_?(Not@*ArrayQ) ] := "Not an array";
myf[arr_?(Nand @@ Positive@Flatten@# &)] := "Not all positive";
myf[arr_] := Reverse@arr

You can substitute Abort[] in the first two cases, if you wish to suspend all calculation after the error is detected. You can also use a Catch/Throw combination.

Test:
{
 myf[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]
 , myf[{{1, 2}, {-3, 4}}]
 , myf[{{1, 2}, {4}}]
 , myf[{1}]
 , myf[{-1, 2}]
 , myf[{1, 2}]
 }



{{{3, 4}, {1,     2}}, "Not all positive", "Not an array", {1}, "Not
all positive", \ {2, 1}}

